# Angular doesn't invoke ngOnInit when programatically routing back to a page

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I've implemented the following console outputs to follow what's executed and what's not. The code for a page under */dataList*.

```
export class DataList implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: DataService) { 
    console.log("constructed");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("inited");
    ...
  }

}
```

Now, it works as supposed providing both the outputs (i.e. *constructed* and *inited*) in the console when accessing the page **by entering a URL** and also when accessing the page using **routing from another page**, as show below.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl("/dataList");
```

However, it doesn't show *initied* (only *constructed*) when I navigate from this page to a detailed page (with URL like */dataElement/12345*, with *12345* being an ID) and then return back to the the page */dataList* executing the navigation by URL shown above. (If I then hit F5, I get to see both *constructed* and *inited*, though.)

I didn't think it was even possible to get into the constructor without getting into `ngOnInit`, given the implemented interface but apparently, I was mistaken (and majorly baffled too).

The best diagnostics that I can up with is that when navigating from a route of subpath, the initialization isn't invoked. But it seems so weird to me so I'm suspect I haven't diagnosed it correctly, neither. Googling produced nothing that I recognized as adequately related ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652845/ngoninit-does-not-get-invoked-when-routing-to-same-component-again-angular-2) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110690/ngoninit-not-being-called-when-injectable-class-is-instantiated/35110798)). And the routing is like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: StartComponent },
  { path: "dataList", component: DataListComponent },
  { path: "dataElement/:id", component: DataElementComponent },
  ...
  { path: "**", component: StartComponent }
];
```

Comment: Do you see this behavior in different browsers?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes, consistent in Cr and FF. Didn't bother to test it in the crappy ones.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8012) reported a similar problem (in 2016) and it was found that the order in which libraries are imported may have some influence. You can check if some librairies are imported after `zone.js` (e.g. in vendor.ts) and change the order to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I had some incredible strike of genius (a.k.a. dumb luck), I got to see see something about a bug in Angular 5 (and some 4s as well). Apparently, the magic to kill this issue looks like this.

```
import { NgZone, ... } from "@angular/core";

export class DataElement implements OnInit {

  constructor(private zone: NgZone, ... ) { ... }

  shaboo() {
    ...
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/dataList");
    });
  }
}
```

Now, I have **no idea** what it does and **even less idea** how nor why. I simply copied a code sample from [this place](http://embed.plnkr.co/H8dhxJDUP6jHdR8rmM9z/) as described in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47480431/1525840). That's the shortest path to not understanding what's going on and I totally hate it, so if someone would like to provide some pointers on the subject, I'd be ecstatic (also, if those explain how such a simple issue can still cause problems in version 5, that'd be even more awesome).